# 16-digit number manipulation in a 32-bit system

Tags: 32-bit, serial-number

I have a simple problem, but because this "programming language" I am using is 32-bit and only supports basic functions such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and concatenation (literally that's it), I am having some trouble.

For the input, I have a 16 digit number like so: **3334,5678,9523,4567**

I want to then subtract 2 other random 16 digit numbers from this number and check if the first and last digits are 1.

For example, if the two other numbers are 1111,1111,1111,1111 and 1234,5678,9123,4565. 
My final number would be: 0988,8888,9288,8891.

Here, the last number is 1, but the first number is 0, so the test would fail.

The issue is with 32-bit systems, there are massive errors due to not enough precision provided by the bits.  What are some ways to bypass this issue?

Comment: If all you're doing is adding and subtracting, write your own *decimal* operations, place  by place, using *string* handling. The only part that takes a bit of thought is handling carrying digits to the next place. Multiplication is almost as simple, but true FP division would take work.

Comment: Represent the 16-digit ***decimal*** numbers as [BCD (binary-coded decimal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) strings.  The precision (i.e. number of digits) is then unlimited.  Some processors even have machine instructions that facilitate BCD arithemtic.

Comment: Have you tried 1111,1111,1111,1111.0+1234,5678,9123,4565.0 ? Most likely the floating-point numbers will have enough precision.

Comment: You don't mention the language.  For many languages, there exist "bignum" [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum] libraries that don't care what the CPU's precision or word size is.  The cost is usually speed, but unless you're performing the operation you describe a billion times a second, you're probably fine.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the language.  Truth is, I don't think it actually has a name.  This is for a super old 1950s client that made their own calculation software and now want us to build them a license key validator using their own software

Comment: I will definitely look into the suggestions here!  Its a really unique problem hahah

Comment: It's difficult to give suggestions without knowing all details about the language, but the standard way **all** languages deal with limited precision is to use multiple machine words. If your addition and subtraction has any kind of carry mechanism (you didn't tell us), or if you have operations that can be used to find out if there is a carry, that's the simplest approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the input, I have a 16 digit number like so: 3334,5678,9523,4567

That is a 16-digit **decimal** number.

> What are some ways to bypass this issue?
>   ... Its [sic] a really unique problem

This is not a new or *"unique"*  problem, and is typically solved with either BCD or multi-word integers.
Floating point, which emphasizes a wide range of magnitude over precision is typically inadequate for a solution, since (binary) double-precision claim up to 16 (decimal) significant digits but is not accurate for decimal fractions (i.e. 1/10 is a infinite binary fraction just like 1/3; see [this article](https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/)).

[BCD (binary-coded decimal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) strings allow unlimited precision (i.e. number of digits).
Some processors even have machine instructions that facilitate BCD arithemtic.
For financial applications there have been decimal (not binary) computers that used BCD arithmetic.

A binary computer with a word size of *N* bits is not constrained to arithmetic of integers of *N* bits.
The carry and borrow flags of the [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) facilitate arithmetic operations of multiple words.
See [this answer to "Reason to use the carry bit and the overflow bit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722785/reason-to-use-the-carry-bit-and-the-overflow-bit/12725143#12725143).

A computation-intensive program would probably prefer a multi-word integer or fixed-point solution for a speed advantage.
An input/output-intensive program (e.g. a calculator) would probably prefer a BCD integer or fixed-point solution for a conversion advantage.  Four-function hand calculators typically use BCD (rather than binary) arithmetic.

---

---

**Addendum**

The two schemes mentioned above can be combined into a hybrid scheme.
Using 32-bit integers a `binary-coded billion` could be used instead of (unpacked) bytes and a `binary-coded decimal`.

Instead of using bytes to store an unpacked value between 0 and 9 (inclusive), expand the concept of BCD to use 32-bit integers that store a value between 0 and 999,999,999 (inclusive).

To represent a 16-digit decimal number, two 32-bit `binary-coded billion` words would be required.
This storage requirement is the same as if a 64-bit integer was used.
 Conversion between binary and decimal radix is faster than pure-binary multiple words, while arithmetic is faster than BCD.
This hybrid scheme inherits the advantages of its origins.

Comment: Thanks sawdust.  My background isnt really in computing science.  I read some materials on BCD just now and will give it a shot.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RuiNian -- Updated answer.